# How to read dictionary consisting string as Key

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a dictionary that consisting string as keys and bool as Value like

```
[{1,1 True}]
[{5,1 True}]
[{5,2 True}]
[{2,4 True}]
```

Here is how i am adding values into Dictionary.

```
string DictKey = (j +","+ (iPageIndex - 1)).ToString();
PageVersusRowCheckboxStatus.Add(DictKey, true);
```

Now i need to traverse the resultant values of dictionary based on second value of the Key.For eaxmple, in the above dictionary 1,1 and 5,1 are the keys.

Is there a way we can loop through based on second value of the above shared Key i.e and and get first one i.e 1 and 5 respectively.

Comment: String access doesn't exist. Internal representation is different than visible f.e. in debugger. What You See Inst What You Have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through `PageVersusRowCheckboxStatus.Keys` and split each one. However, you would probably be better off using `Tuple<int,int>` as the key type instead of string:

```
Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, bool> PageVersusRowCheckboxStatus = 
    new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, bool>();

//...

var DictKey = new Tuple<int, int>(j, iPageIndex - 1);
PageVersusRowCheckboxStatus.Add(DictKey, true);


var q = 
    PageVersusRowCheckboxStatus.Keys
        .Where(t => t.Item2 == 1)
        .Select(t => t.Item1);
```

If you use a string and split it all the time, your code gets cluttered with weird stuff, and every time you need to deal with the two parts of the key you've got to remember how the splitting works. It's easier to write, easier to debug, and easier to maintain if you use a class that has two int properties.

Here's a question, though: What are you doing with the bool values in the dictionary? If you just put them there as a placeholder, you might be better off with

```
List<Tuple<int, int>>
```

Or

```
HashSet<Tuple<int, int>>
```

@O.R.Mapper points out that if hyper-efficiency isn't a big concern (and it very, very often is not), this could be very simple and effective:

```
List<Tuple<int, int, bool>>
```

If you're only looking things up by page index, you're not getting any benefit from using a dictionary. You can iterate through all the keys, but you can't look up values by partial key. In fact, it's possible that this is what you want:

```
var dict = new PageVersusRowCheckboxStatus();

dict.SetRowStatus(2, 1, true);
dict.SetRowStatus(2, 5, true);
dict.SetRowStatus(3, 5, true);
dict.SetRowStatus(4, 2, true);

// ...

//  Here's how to do the query that returns ( 1, 5 ) for page index key 1
int pageIndexKey = 1;
if (dict.ContainsKey(pageIndexKey))
{
    foreach (int row in dict[pageIndexKey].Keys)
    {
        //  Do something
    }
}

// ...

public class RowStatusDictionary : Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, bool>>
{
    public void SetRowStatus(int pageIndex, int row, bool status)
    {
        Dictionary<int, bool> rowStatuses = null;

        int pageIndexKey = pageIndex - 1;

        if (!this.TryGetValue(pageIndexKey, out rowStatuses))
        {
            this[pageIndexKey] = new Dictionary<int, bool>();
        }

        rowStatuses[row] = status;
    }

    public bool GetRowStatus(int pageIndex, int row)
    {
        Dictionary<int, bool> rowStatuses = null;

        int pageIndexKey = pageIndex - 1;

        if (TryGetValue(pageIndexKey, out rowStatuses))
        {
            return rowStatuses[row];
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely it's better way to do it :)

Comment: But that way, any advantage of a dictionary versus a simple list is lost.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Can you clarify?

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Accessing items in a dictionary by their key is fast because the dictionary internally uses a hashtable. Hence, the dictionary will not iterate over (possibly) all items to find an item with a particular key. Once you use `Where` and `Select`, though, you circumvent that hashtable and instead enumerate all items sequentially until you find the one searched for - thereby reducing the performance to that of a flat list.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Dictionary doesn't support lookup by part of the key if it's a string either. In fact nothing OP is doing in the question uses the dictionary as a dictionary -- perhaps the bool values will change. If not, then yes, the answer is to use `List<Tuple<int, int>>` instead.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Or `List<Tuple<int, int, bool>>`, yes. I know dictionary doesn't support lookup by part of the key. I commented because whenever someone uses a dictionary, I have found chances are the respective programmer has heard a dictionary is somehow faster than a list, but is unaware that this is not automatically true just by using a dictionary. Hence, I found it worthwhile to mention.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper For a bit there I wasn't sure if he was using the bool, then reread OP. Not surprised if people use dictionaries for voodoo reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested, but you can do something similar:

```
IEnumerable<string> keys = dict.Where(a => a.Key.Split(',')[1] == "1").Select(a => a.Key.Split(',')[0]);
```

with this you'll get what you want.

Note: If you want to work with `List<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` then you can use `ToList()` extension method

Comment: If he wants to loop through it, a better solution might be 

`dict.OrderBy(a => a.Key.Split(',')[1])`

Or possibly even

`dict.OrderBy(a => int.Parse(a.Key.Split(',')[1])).ThenBy(a => int.Parse(a.Key.Split(',')[0]))`

Comment: But that way, any advantage of a dictionary versus a simple list is lost.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Could you please let me know where to store the value that comes from `PageVersusRowCheckboxStatus.Where(a => a.Key.Split(',')[iPageIndex] == iPageIndex.ToString()).Select(a => a.Key[0]);` . Do i need to store in List, I am not able to get any value. Please suggest

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Could you please let me know where to store the value that comes from PageVersusRowCheckboxStatus.Where(a => a.Key.Split(',')[iPageIndex] == iPageIndex.ToString()).Select(a => a.Key[0]); . Do i need to store in List, I am not able to get any value. Please suggest

Comment: @Lara I've edited initial answer. Please note that previously written Select(a => a.Key[0]) will return IEnumerable<char> which is something you want to avoid I assume.

Comment: I used the updated line like `IEnumerable<string> keys = PageVersusRowCheckboxStatus.Where(a => a.Key.Split(',')[iPageIndex] == iPageIndex.ToString()).Select(a => a.Key.Split(',')[0]);` but still i am getting NULL. MY Dictionary contains the same set of value i added in my Post above. Could you please  guide. Thanks

Comment: @Lara you should use fixed index on the array after Split() method. So, IEnumerable<string> keys = PageVersusRowCheckboxStatus.Where(a => a.Key.Split(',')[1] == iPageIndex.ToString()).Select(a => a.Key.Split(',')[0]);

Comment: I am sorry but still i am getting NULL

Comment: @Lara split chained LINQ methods and then debug each step. Maybe filter lamda doesn't work properly. You could also rewrite lambda into a => { return a.Key.Split(',')[1] == iPageIndex.ToString(); } so you can step into with debugger

Comment: @DarjanBogdan I am sorry to tell again but i am still getting `NULL` by adding this line `IEnumerable<string> keys = PageVersusRowCheckboxStatus.Where(a => { return a.Key.Split(',')[1] == iPageIndex.ToString(); }).Select(a => a.Key.Split(',')[0]);`

Comment: @Lara that line is exactly the same as line in my initial answer, you should break down that lambda into multiple rows. After that you'll be able to attach debugger to that line of code. I assume you have some data inconsistency, so step into that lambda to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include two values in your dictionary keys, a better solution might be to have your key type be a `Tuple<int, int>` instead of a comma delimited string. Or possibly just a custom class

`public class DictKey{
    public int row {get; set;} 
    public int pageIndex {get; set;}
}`

You might want to consider ignoring the page entirely, and give each checkbox its own id, irrespective of what page it's on.